# Set Eclipse project location out of workspace

Tags: php, eclipse, git, workspace

I want to change the source location of a PHP project to be out of workspace in Eclipse.

For example, workspace is in `/home/user/workspace/project` and source code placed in `/var/html/project`.

I don't want to make a copy of project in the workspace for two reasons:

1. Because the source is a git repository and I'm not allowed to change the `.gitignore` file, I don't want any metadata to be saved in the source folder.
2. I'm using the source in multiple projects and workspaces.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just move your project in the filesystem to `/var/html/project`. Then in eclipse open the `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace` dialog. Lookup `/var/html/project` and leave the checkbox `Copy projects into workspace` unchecked.